# Is there hardware_interface::RobotHW in ros2?

Tags: ros, ros2, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I'm porting my project from ros1 Noetic to ros2 Foxy right now and can't find hardware_interface::RobotHW or something that inherit it functionality. I'll appreciate for any hint what and there to look.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407713/is-there-hardware_interface::robothw-in-ros2?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-13**:
@Edvard: could you please not close questions when they've been answered?

On ROS Answers, we mark such questions as *answered* by ticking the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer. It should turn green.

thanks

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-13**:
OK, I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quoting from the [documentation](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/differences_to_ros1/differences_to_ros1.html):

> The implementation of `RobotHW` is not used anymore. This should be migrated to `SystemInterface` class or, for more granularity, `SensorInterface` and `ActuatorInterface`.

I suggest reading the documentation at the following link:
https://control.ros.org/master/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-13**:
Thank you for your help